# Show Hide Text using JavaScript by words not characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found this code that works great, but it counts by characters. As a result the words sometimes are incomplete, and when you click on read more it creates a space in the word. I have also found a function of how to count by words, but I don't have the know how to merge the two. Below is my working code, and the function
Thanks

====== Working Code ======

```js
// Show more text option -campaing page
    var showChar = 196;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Read more";
    var lesstext = "Read less";
    
    //Cut content based on showChar length
    if ($(".toggle-text").length) {
        $(".toggle-text").each(function() {

            var content = $(this).html();
     
            if(content.length > showChar) {
     
                var contentExcert = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var contentRest = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
                var html = contentExcert + '<span class="toggle-text-ellipses">' + ellipsestext + ' </span> <span class="toggle-text-content"><span>' + contentRest + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn--primary btn--dark toggle-text-link">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
     
                $(this).html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    
    //Toggle content when click on read more link
    $(".toggle-text-link").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

====== Function Code ======

```js
function limitWords(element, quantity){

   var text = $(element).text();

   var words = text.split(" ");

   quantity = Math.min( quantity, words.length );

   $(element).text( words.slice(0,quantity) + "..." );

}
```

Comment: Javascript.  Javascript != Java.

Comment: You do not know how to merge, we do not know what you want to do. Tell us what you want to do in the end. Give us some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
var charCount = 0;
var contentExcert = content.split(" ").map((n)=>{
    charCount += n.length + 1;
    return charCount - 1 <= showChar ? n : false;
}).filter(n=>n).join(" ");
charCount = 0;
var contentRest = content.split(" ").map((n)=>{
    charCount += n.length + 1;
    return charCount - 1 >= showChar ? n : false;
}).filter(n=>n).join(" ");
```

Comment: Thats what I needed! I have posted the merged code. If something does not look right please let me know

Comment: You should modify your question to something like... "How can I split a string so that it doesn't contain more than a certain number of characters without resulting in partial words?"

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Show more text option -campaing page
    var showChar = 196;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Read more";
    var lesstext = "Read less";
    
    //Cut content based on showChar length
    if ($(".toggle-text").length) {
        $(".toggle-text").each(function() {

            var content = $(this).html();
     
            if(content.length > showChar) {
     
    var charCount = 0;
    var contentExcert = content.split(" ").map((n)=>{
     charCount += n.length + 1;
     return charCount - 1 <= showChar ? n : false;
     }).filter(n=>n).join(" ");
     charCount = 0;
    var contentRest = content.split(" ").map((n)=>{
     charCount += n.length + 1;
     return charCount - 1 >= showChar ? n : false;
     }).filter(n=>n).join(" ");
                var html = contentExcert + '<span class="toggle-text-ellipses">' + ellipsestext + ' </span> <span class="toggle-text-content"><span>' + contentRest + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn--primary btn--dark toggle-text-link">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
     
                $(this).html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    
    //Toggle content when click on read more link
    $(".toggle-text-link").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```